# How do iOS applications get arguments if it doesn't return to main?

Tags: ios, arguments

I'm reading Big Nerd Ranch iOS programming 4th edition. In chapter 7's "for the more curious"  it states that an instance of UIApplication is created for the run loop and that it will never return to main. **How does the application get new arguments from the OS then?**

I was under the assumption that the main function was the only way that an application could **receive** arguments unless it specifically requests them. So then what if **the OS wants to send it** an argument after it has already been ran?

Am I understanding what an argument is wrong? From what I understand it is data from another program or OS that is used as input. This piece of information I read confused me.

Comment: arguments like what, argc/argv in a traditional c app? there's plenty of ways of accomplishing inter-process communication (IPC). ios has notification systems that allow ios to "talk" to an app, and for the app to respond.

Comment: The arguments sent to `main` are the ones passed at the time the program is executed. `main` can't be used by any `C` based program to receive further arguments during runtime. This is true of a Mac or iOS app written in Objective-C or a Windows program written in C.

Comment: Arguments are strings that a program receives upon startup. They aren't intended for continuous interprocess communication while the program runs.

Comment: Thank you guys, yes this is what I was referring to by "arguments."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS App never get arguments via main when installed on iDevice (what about JB, I don't know).

App receive data from outside via :

```
AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```